# Favicon Image not showing in base.html

Tags: django

I am trying to add an image in the favicon but it is not showing for some reason in the template base.html and it is showing only in another template only called: who_we_are.html I have also written its views.py below.

I want it in the base to show on all pages. This an app called marketing in a project, I think the reason is not showing because of the URLs is not reading the base HTML

I have written the models.py with function as following:

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    favicon = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, upload_to='Marketing', verbose_name="Pages Icon")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_favicon(self):
        return "%s/%s" % (settings.MEDIA_URL, self.favicon)
```

Here is the views.py

```
def base(request):
    setting = Setting.objects.get()
    template = 'base.html'
    context = {'setting': setting}
    return render(request, template, context)


def who_we_are(request):
    setting = Setting.objects.get()
    template = 'who_we_are.html'
    context = {'setting': setting}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

here is the base.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" class="rounded-circle" href="{{ setting.get_favicon }}" type="image/jpg" sizes="16x16">
```

This is the URLs

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('who_we_Are/', who_we_are, name='who_we_are'),
]
```

Thank you

Comment: This should be `{{ setting.favicon.url }}`.

Comment: No that is not it but I am thinking should the base be in the URLs?

Comment: hey man you unmarked the answer, did the solution not work?

Comment: @sahil sorry I clicked it by mistake, I think the problem is with the url it is not reading the base

Comment: you should check what's the output of get_favicon on python shell.

Comment: I have edited my answer try that maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model property `get_favicon` is returning `MEDIA_URL` and an `ImageField` object you can modify your method to return the URL of favicon.

EDIT- Try adding `@property` decorator above your `get_favicon` method.

```
@property
def get_favicon(self):
    return self.favicon.url
```

Comment: You don't need to have anything in your urls.py as long as you have your MEDIA_URL setup in settings.py and MEDIA_ROOT using self.favicon.url should work